# How do I give an alias name to the values printed by dbms output in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, rdbms, database-cursor

I have this following code which prints the department number and department name from dept table whose department number is less than 40.

```
declare
cursor cn is select dno, dname from dept where dno<40;
v_dno dept.dno%type;
v_dname dept.dname%TYPE;
begin
    open cn;
        loop
            fetch cn into v_dno,v_dname;
            dbms_output.put_line(v_dno||' '||v_dname);
            exit when cn%notfound;
        end loop;
    close cn;
end;
```

This is the output I got:

```
10 Administration
20 Marketing
30 Purchasing
30 Purchasing
```

But the output that I'm expecting is:

```
Department_No   Department_Name
10              Administration
20              Marketing
30              Purchasing
30              Purchasing
```

Comment: In addition to the other comments, you need to understand that dbms_output executes entirely inside the database engine and so does _not_ write to your screen.  It writes to an internal buffer. On completion of the procedure, when control is passed back to the calling client, the client may (or may not) choose to process that buffer and display the results.  As a result, it is not a good idea to use dbms_output for other than demos or debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PL/SQL only outputs what we explicitly pass to DBMS_OUTPUT. So, if you want headings you need to provide them yourself:

```
declare
cursor cn is select dno, dname from dept where dno<40;
v_dno dept.dno%type;
v_dname dept.dname%TYPE;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Department_No   Department_Name');
    open cn;
        loop
            fetch cn into v_dno,v_dname;
            dbms_output.put_line(rpad(to_char(v_dno),14)||' '||v_dname);
            exit when cn%notfound;
        end loop;
    close cn;
end;
```

Note that to get the neat alignment you need to use `RPAD()` to make V_DNO same length as the heading

Comment: Thank you very much :))))

But why do you change the V_dno to character?

Comment: Because it's clearer. DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE only displays strings, so it is **implicitly** casting V_NO to a varchar2 anyway. I just think it's better practice to make such things explicit.

Comment: Thank you for this info. Will follow it up from now on.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to display it separately (see line #10) (I used Scott's sample `DEPT` table as I don't have yours):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     CURSOR cn IS
  3        SELECT deptno, dname
  4          FROM dept
  5         WHERE deptno < 40;
  6
  7     v_deptno  dept.deptno%TYPE;
  8     v_dname   dept.dname%TYPE;
  9  BEGIN
 10     DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Department_no   Department_name');
 11
 12     OPEN cn;
 13
 14     LOOP
 15        FETCH cn INTO v_deptno, v_dname;
 16
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (RPAD (v_deptno, 15, ' ') || ' ' || v_dname);
 18        EXIT WHEN cn%NOTFOUND;
 19     END LOOP;
 20
 21     CLOSE cn;
 22  END;
 23  /
Department_no   Department_name
10              ACCOUNTING
20              RESEARCH
30              SALES
30              SALES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write combination of plsql & html code. As like

```
declare
cursor cn is select dno, dname from dept where dno<40;
begin
htp.p('<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Department_no<\th>
        <th>Department_name<\th>
    <\tr>');
for i in cn
    loop
htp.p('<tr>
        <td>'|| i.dno ||'<\td>
        <td>'|| i.dname ||'<\td>
    <\tr>');
    end loop;
htp.p('<\table>');
end;
```